# Magento2: Customer automatic log out. | customer session

Tags: magento2

The client on my site will be automatically logged out after x time.

How to disable it off or increase this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Go** to **System** -> **Configuration** -> **Web** -> **Session Cookie Management** and **Set Cookie Lifetime**